# index doesn't update

Tags: search

I'm using Drupal 8's built-in search and it will not update the index.

I have cron running every 15 minutes and even tried running it manually but the search status page always says:

**"0% of the site has been indexed. There are 80300 items left to index."**

Another odd thing is that **some** nodes appear to be indexed, even though the status report says zero, because some (but not all) nodes will appear when searched for.

Any ideas what's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved. The issue was a malformed URI that was imported from the Drupal 6 website. The search indexing failed when it encountered this content (comment).

It turns out that it was old spam comments from the D6 site. I was able to delete those and indexing is working now.